# OpenCV Stitching

Tags: c++, opencv, image-stitching, panoramas

I desperately need help with the opencv stitching module. I need to create a panoramic photography using the "stitch" method in opencv. Below is what I have so far.. but when I run the program I get this error: Need more images. Is there an OpenCV expert who can help me with this error?

```
IplImage* img1 = cvLoadImage("/Users/myName/Desktop/image1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
IplImage* img2 = cvLoadImage("/Users/myName/Desktop/image2.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

Mat vecImg1 = img1;
Mat vecImg2 = img2;

Mat allImages;

allImages.push_back(vecImg1);
allImages.push_back(vecImg2);

Mat outputImage;
Stitcher stitchImg = Stitcher::createDefault();
Stitcher::Status s = stitchImg.stitch(allImages, outputImage);
cout << "status: " << s << endl;

cvNamedWindow("stitch images", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cvShowImage("stitch images", &outputImage);
cvWaitKey(0);
cvDestroyWindow("stitch images");
```

Comment: I'm not an OpenCV expert, but did you try adding more images to your `allImages`?

Comment: Two images should be sufficient. Is there enough overlap between them?

Comment: Yes, there is a sufficient overlap between two since they were sample images to perform stitching.. :(

Comment: Why don't you start with the sample code provided by OpenCV?

Answer (score 4):

I guess "allImages" should be of type `vector<Mat>`.

Check out OpenCV sample "samples/cpp/stitching.cpp".

Comment: If I change allImages to vector<Mat> then, I get an error saying "cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(std::__1::vector<cv::Mat, std::__1::allocator<cv::Mat> > const&)"

Comment: It's saying, Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Comment: I referred to stitching.cpp but I keep getting errors.. :(     .

Answer (score 1):

I actually found a way around.

In Xcode, under the Build Settings, I changed the Compiler type from Apple LLVM to LLVM GCC 4.2 and now my code generates panorama image just fine!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the stitcher class function, opencv find feature matches between images. If the image you have entered have no or very less features in common, it will not treat these images as image of same view
Hence more images required